# Do I have to use vertexArray in opengl

Tags: opengl, vertex-arrays

```
GLuint VertexArrayID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);
```

As you can see from the above code, some tutorials use this before using opengl. But a tutorial that I am following, directly uses `glGenBuffers`  method and it works just fine. Hence I am totally confused what `glGenVertexArrays`. It is sad that it defines how buffer is used, but noone says in what way. Can you help me understand ?

Comment: VAOs and VBOs (`glGenBuffers`) are two different things. You might benefit from reading an [answer I wrote on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23314787/use-of-vertex-array-objects-and-vertex-buffer-objects/23315318#23315318).

Answer (score 3):

If you use OpenGL 3.2, it's required.